# Validate Date in the request body

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a request body have date field and I want to validate the input of the date and return error code 400 BadRequest if the format is wrong.

If I use the `JsonFormat` then it throws error 500:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date dateAt;
```

So I changed the field to `String` and then parse and throw BadRequest format everywhere using the `getDate()`

I am not really satisfied with this approach. Is there any other elegant way to achieve this validation?

---

I think I will accept error 500 from JSON formatter and skip my custom exception.

Comment: How do you implement your controller for validation? Could you also post the code snippet?

Comment: I do not validate in controller but service layer. I try to put it in `try-catch` block and then throw new `BadRequestException` if `parse()` could not be implemented. Anyways, I think I will skip this and accept the way JSON returns 500 error when date format is incorrect. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java 8, you should avoid using [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html). Java 8 brought an entirely new [date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

According to your question, a suitable replacement for [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) would be [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html), which is expected to be in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Jackson has a [module](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) supporting the new date and time API and an exception will be thrown if the date is not in the correct format. When serializing, you want to make sure the [`WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) feature is disabled, so the values will be written according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

Comment: I'd wager you mean [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)?

Comment: @daniu Yes! That's the one I meant :)